# How to get the name of a control that has started an event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get the name of the control that's start an event, in particular I've used a ContextMenu for DataGrid, this is the code that I actually write:

```
private void ClearTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Try to cast the sender to a MenuItem
    ContextMenu menuItem = sender as ContextMenu;
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        // Retrieve the ContextMenu that contains this MenuItem
        ContextMenu menu = menuItem.GetContextMenu();

        // Get the control that is displaying this context menu
        Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
 <ContextMenu x:Key="Squadre_ContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Pulisci Tabella" Click="ClearTable_Click">
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Elimina Riga selezionata" Click="ClearRow_Click">
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
```

but the ContextMenu doesn't have the method GetContextMenu, so this is a problem for me. There's a way to fix this or another way to do this?

Comment: The sender parameter is the control.

Comment: I guess your `menuItem` variable should be of type `MenuItem` instead of `ContextMenu`

Comment: I quess you don't want name of the control that fired the event, which is MenuItem in this case but you want the control that showed the ContextMenu, right?

Comment: But I've a context menu in the xaml not a menu item

Comment: and ContextMenu contains MenuItem, right? show the piece of xaml, where you defined the contextmenu

Comment: Yeah, see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void ClearTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Try to cast the sender to a Control
    Control ctrl = sender as Control;
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        // Get the control name
        string name = ctrl.Name;

        // Get parent control name
        Control parent = (Control) ctrl.Parent;
        string parentName = parent.Name
    }
}
```

EDIT: added code to get parent control's name

Comment: when I do Console.WriteLine(t.Name); I get null value

Comment: Does the control have a name specified in your `xaml`?

Comment: Neither of your two MenuItems don't have `Name` attribute. Since one of them is the source, they need to have `Name` attributes so you can have a value in the `Name` property.

Comment: Okay, but is possible get the name Squadre_ContextMenu instead of the menuitem name?

Comment: You could check for `Control.Parent`

Comment: @MrPaulch you beat me on this one :)

Comment: You can not implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject "in" System.Windows.Controls.Control "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87798/discussion-between-bender-and-nevca).

Answer (score 0):

An example taking the sender object as MenuItem and then getting the ContextMenu for a TextBlock control:

```
MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;

if (mi != null)
{
    ContextMenu cm = mi.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;

    if (cm != null)
    {
        TextBlock t = cm.PlacementTarget as TextBlock;
        if (t != null)
        {
            // print t.Name or whatever...
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when I do Console.WriteLine(t.Name); I get null value

Comment: Which control are you targeting? Is a TextBlock as well?

Answer (score 0):

I made a form with a datagridview and I get the name with no problems

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            int l_Index = 0;

            InitializeComponent();

            MenuItem[] l_MenuItems = new MenuItem[3];

            for (l_Index = 0; l_Index < l_MenuItems.Length; l_Index++)
            {
                l_MenuItems[l_Index] = new MenuItem("Menu " + l_Index.ToString(), MenuItem_Click);
            }

            System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu l_ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(l_MenuItems);

            dataGridView1.ContextMenu = l_ContextMenu;
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem l_MenuItem = sender as MenuItem;

            if (l_MenuItem != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu l_ContextMenu = l_MenuItem.GetContextMenu();

                if (l_ContextMenu != null)
                {
                    if (l_ContextMenu.SourceControl != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(l_ContextMenu.SourceControl.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                dataGridView1.ContextMenu.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you have bug in your code. your `menuItem` variable will be always `null`, because sender is `MenuItem` actually, since you assigned `ClearTable_Click` to MenuItem, not ContextMenu.

Second, in order to get ContextMenu from MenuItem, you need to look at VisualTree and search for MenuItem's parent of type context menu. There is API called [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Alternativelly, you can use `GetSelfAndAncestors` helper method from System.Windows.Interactivity.dll:

```
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

private void ClearTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender; //MenuItem that fired the click event
    var contextMenu = menuItem.GetSelfAndAncestors().OfType<ContextMenu>().First()
    UIElement sourceControl = menu.PlacementTarget;
}
```